# Is there a way-around solution of `expose-aside-when` with Ionic2?

Tags: angular, ionic2

With Ionic 2, Is there a way to expose side menu all the time when screen is greater than 768px?

There is "expose-aside-when" in Ionic 1, not in Ionic 2.

NOTE: I found a solution, but not working with the recent release. https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/expose-aside-when-in-ionic-2/42949

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that this is a good solution, but at least I can see the side menu all the time.

```
@media (min-width: 767px) {
  ion-menu {  /* always show menu */
    display: block;
  }

  .menu-inner {  /* always show menu */
    transform: translateX(0px) !important;
  }

  ion-nav.menu-content { /* always show menu content */
    cursor: pointer;
    -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
    touch-action: manipulation;
    transform: translateX(304px !important);
  }

  .ion-page { /* recalculate page contents width deducted by menu width */
    width: calc(100% - 304px);
  }

  button[menutoggle] { /* hide all non-working menu buttons */
    display: none;
  }
}
```

The problem with this solution is that I cannot show and hide menu any more. It's always there.

If I really want to show/hide menu, I have to add a custom code for it.